# How to handle time series data in ANN?

Tags: neural-network, overfitting

I want to use ANN to forecast the next #games played in my mobile game.  There are 39 features: 9 features that describe the player's state (level, amount of in game-currencies, etc.) and the last 30 game-days (= number of games played condition the player played at least 0 games).

Initially I sampled each player once. However I think it is possible to improve the accuracy of the model by increasing the number of samples (currently I have 1.8M samples).  So I looked at historical data: I sampled each player, and each game-day in the last 180 days.

Should I use just one sample from each user every 30 game-days? Since right now two adjacent samples are identical in 28 out of 30 game-days (with a shift of +1).  My concern is that e.g., the data will have 28 samples where after a day of 104 games comes a day of 30, will this could make an overfit problem?

[image]

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Masking
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
from joblib import dump, load

# Split the data into training and testing sets
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

# Replace NaN values to 0
X_train = X_train.fillna(0)
X_test = X_test.fillna(0)

# Standardize the data (optional but recommended for neural networks)
scaler = StandardScaler()
X_train_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test_scaled = scaler.transform(X_test)
dump(scaler, '/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/forecasting GPD/GPD_Forecasting_NN_Model.joblib')  # save the scaler

# Define the model with a Masking layer
model = Sequential()
model.add(Masking(mask_value=0., input_shape=(X_train_scaled.shape[1],)))
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(42, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear'))  # Linear activation for regression
model.summary()

# Compile the model
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error')

# Define early stopping callback
early_stopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=5, restore_best_weights=True)

# Fit the model to your data
history = model.fit(X_train_scaled, y_train, epochs=30, batch_size=42, validation_data=(X_test_scaled, y_test), callbacks=[early_stopping])

# Evaluate the model
mse_nn = model.evaluate(X_test_scaled, y_test)
print('Mean Squared_error (Neural Network):', round(mse_nn, 3))

# Save the model to a file
model.save("/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/forecasting GPD/GPD_Forecasting_NN_Model.keras")
```